# .NET Core project dependency "bleed"

Tags: c#, reference, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Reference encapsulation in .NET Core seems to have changed in a way which allows references in one project to "bleed" into another project.

In prior versions of .NET, assemblies referenced by project "X" were not exposed to other projects in the solution which referenced project "X".

So for example, if you had a **Domain** project which referenced **Entity Framework**, adding a reference to that **Domain** project to another project in your solution would not grant that other project access to any Entity Framework classes.

This was a good thing (at least in my opinion).

Was playing around with a .NET Core 2.1 app tonight, and created a domain project 
which leveraged EF Core.

I then created a unit test project (in eager anticipation of leveraging the new EF Core InMemory provider), and referenced my domain project.

What completely caught me off guard was that the unit test project was able to access EF Core classes even though I did not bring the EF Core NuGet package into the unit test project;  my only assumption is that it was able to access EF via my domain project, ie:

[image: Example of the reference bleed]

This seems highly undesirable;  I don't care too much about reference bleeds in my unit tests, but I do care very much about this kind reference bleed when working with other projects in my solution (such as an ASP.NET Core Web project).

Is there a way to hide / shield these package references in my **Domain** project from other projects which reference it?

Comment: I have noticed that nuget packages is not only thing which 'bleeds'. Even if you will  change a reference chain: App -> Library1 -> Library2 you will also be able to use Library2 classes in App directly. Thanks to @TheGeneral answer I found that `PrivateAssets` can be also used with referenced projects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a curious thing and i have never noticed it before,

However take a look at this

[Controlling dependency assets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files)

> **PrivateAssets** These assets will be consumed but won't flow to the
>   parent project

And the tag

> **compile**   Contents of the lib folder and controls whether your project
>   can compile against the assemblies within the folder

Right click `Class library -> Dependencies -> Nuget -> Package`, and set the `PrivateAssets` to the word `compile`... I was seemingly able to use (and yet hide the dependency) in a calling .Net Core project.

**Disclaimer**, i really only played with this setting out of curiosity, and not really sure if there are any side affects to doing this

Comment: The "compile" keyword worked perfectly;  the "all" keyword was a bit too restrictive  (it prevented certain libraries, such as System.Linq.Dynamic.Core from being dynamically loaded).  Its a shame that the AddDbContext extension method for ASP.NET Core's IServiceCollection requires the full EF Core package - somewhat defeats my desire to restrict that reference to just my domain project.

Comment: @RMD that was my experience as well

Comment: For an unknown reason, I cannot change `Private Assets` property from the IDE, but by editing the .csproj file, this solution worked for me.